# Unwanted effect in Schlieren Imaging

Tags: optics, diffraction

We're building a Schlieren Setup essentially equivalent to the following one:

[image: system sketch]

We have a test area where there exists a beam of collimated white light coming from the left that is later focused by an achromatic converging lense. The original light source is 1mm diameter LED so this is the image  we get in the focal plane of the lense.

Now we place a cut-off (a knife edge in our particular case though it could be a pinhole or any other kind of spatial filter) in the focus point of the lense so it blocks part of the light that would otherwise reach the camera.

Sensitivity in this sort of system is given by $S=F/a$ being $F$ the focal lenght and $a$ the vertical dimension of the unobstructed image (in the following image we illustrate this further)

[image: cut-off example]

Given this relation, in order to increase sensitivity, we should play with $a$ given that $F$ is fixed. Theoretically, if the cut-off is placed just at the focal point of the lense, decreasing $a$ results in an uniform darkening of the image captured by the camera so, if no object is present in the test area a gray background should be observed.

Now that we've introduced the system, we'll pose the questions

1) If the cut-off is removed, a white image is formed in the camera. By slowly introducing the knife edge, it gets "uniformly" darker until some point (certain $a$) when the colours below appear.
Any ideas why we are getting pictures like the following instead of the uniform gray background? Sensitivity has an upper limit due to diffraction issues but I don't think this is our case (at least we don't know how diffraction can result in getting blue and yellow zones). Also we thought that it could be due to some reflection in the knife edge (since it is pretty close to the camera's teleobjective) but it doesn't seem to be the answer either. [left - what is supposed to be an uniform gray background; right - same with the hot air plume in the test area]

[image: bgblueyellow]
[image: plumeblueyellow]

2) When an object is present, we can get a focused image of it in the camera, but the schlieren effect appears a little blurry. Take the next picture as an example. The candle itself is captured with a good resolution but the plume of hot air is blurry. It's not due to vibration or anything like that since same problem arise when observing similar pictures of more steady flows. 
This might be due to the effect forming an image not in $s'$ but in a different place and the question then would be where this image is formed.

[image: blurryschlieren]

Any help is more than appreciated.
Thank you all in advance for your time!

Besides, I'm new here so any mistakes I made please let me know so I can edit the post.

Comment: For debugging purposes, I would first simplify your setup by removing the knife-edge for now. Do you then get a uniform background image? If not, and if you have a radially asymmetric image like your first photo, then you may have some misalignment in your system such as your lens being slightly tilted with respect to the axis of the setup. Another thing you might consider is to use a monochromatic LED (e.g., red LED) rather than a white one since a white LED puts more demands on your entire system being truly achromatic. For example, the lens on your white LED may not be an achromatic one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Samuel. The system forms a white image at the end. By slowly introducing the cut-off it gets "uniformly" darker until some point when the colours appear. I know diffraction issues can happen if some threshold is reached but neither I think that I got that far nor what I get is a diffraction problem. Sorry if this point was unclear in the original post. I'll edit in a moment. Thank you for the tips on debugging!

Comment: Red light diffracts more than blue light, so maybe the blue fringe in your first photograph is due to the knife edge starting to cause some of the red light to diffract out of the light path. Also, I know that historically Schlieren has used knife edges but it's always seemed to me that a properly sized pinhole would be a more appropriate spatial filter. Probably a lot more difficult to align, though.

Comment: Thanks again. I thought the same about the blue light at first but discarded that idea because of the yellow fringe appearing at the same time which led me to think it's not a diffraction issue, or at least not only that. Regarding the use of a pinhole as a cut-off, as far as I know, that would only change what component of refractive index gradient I would be measuring. With an horizontal knife changes of refractive index in the vertical direction are measured while with a pinhole we would be examining the radial component of this variation. Anyway, I'll look further into this. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Do you also use an achromatic lens to collimate LED light? If not, it will introduce chromatic aberrations regardless of what lens you use to focus the light. Also, 1 mm may be too large for a point source, you may want to add a pinhole in front of the LED 2) Try to focus the camera on the Schlieren picture and not on the candle. You may use a glass stick or other refracting object to create a strong, static Schlieren image.

Comment: Hello @gigacyan and thanks for your time. 1) Yes, two achromatic pairs, one to collimate light from the point source and the focusing one. Since I only get the effect when decreasing $a$, I think the problem is not chromatic aberrations. Anyway I'll check if there's something I'm missing regarding this. I'll give your pinhole idea a try and see if it gets any better. 2) Since the hot air plume is generated in top of the candle I don't fully understand how the Schlieren image could be formed anywhere else so I don't exactly know where to focus the camera on in that case.

Comment: @CharlieBoqueron  You are probably right about focusing. Also, in my setup everything between the two achromatic lenses (~40 cm) is reasonably sharp so I did not have to set the focus exactly. Flame can be blurred due to gas mixing in the boundary layer. Try a gas lighter without flame - a thin stream of propane that comes out gives clear and sharp picture.